# .htaccess url friendly in php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I want to turn a url in the url friendly.
my url:

> `http://www.builtbydoctors.com/qrcode/index.php?id=93`

and i want this url friendly:

```
http://www.builtbydoctors.com/qrcode/**title**/93
```

the title changes depending on the id.

my problem is in the htaccess file in the creation of the regular expression. there have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$2&nome=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I know that the problem is in the htaccess file, can help me solve this problem in regular expression?

Comment: How do you get __title__ when it's not in the URI?

Comment: try this `RewriteRule ^qrcode/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$2&nome=$1 [NC]`

Comment: The friendly url is created in the database, and when it is accessed want her to do the same as not friendly url. I do understand me?

Comment: and this `RewriteRule ^qrcode/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC]` | `name` or `nome`

Answer (score 2):

Your rule will work for url

```
http://www.builtbydoctors.com/index/title/93
```

If you want use it for your example then you should change your rule to

```
RewriteRule ^qrcode/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$2&nome=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: What url do you try? And also try change first regexp to ([a-z0-9]+)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do so

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Using this you can tell Rewrite to have a base url
    RewriteBase /qrcode
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$2&nome=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Hope that works!